# Parsing JSON data and populating ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am getting issue while parsing json Data and populating list view.

For an example below is the json data i am trying to parse and the rest of sample code which shows what i am trying to achieve.

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "abcd",
        "department": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "code": 4536
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "abcd",
        "department": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "code": 4536
        }
    }
]
```

This is my main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView employeeListView;
    private Employee employees[];
    private ArrayAdapter<Employee> employeeArrayAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        employeeListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.employeeListView);
    }

    public void updateListView(){
        String a="[{\"id\":123,\"name\":\"abcd\",\"department\":{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"code\":4536}},{\"id\":123,\"name\":\"abcd\",\"department\":{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"code\":4536}}]";
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(a);
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            employees=new Employee[jsonArray.length()];
            Employee employee;
            Employee.Department department;
            int x=0;
            while(x<jsonArray.length()){
                jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                employee=new Employee();
                department=employee.new Department();
                employee.setCode(jsonObject.optInt("id"));
                employee.setName(jsonObject.optString("name"));
                JSONObject jsonDepartment=jsonObject.getJSONObject("department");
                department.setDepartmentName(jsonDepartment.optString("name"));
                department.setDepartmentCode(jsonDepartment.optInt("code"));
                employee.setDepartment(department);
                employees[x]=employee;
                x++;
            }
            employeeArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,employees);
            employeeListView.setAdapter(employeeArrayAdapter);
        }catch (Throwable t){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        updateListView();
    }   
}
```

And this is my pojo class

```
public class Employee {
    private int code;
    private String name;
    private Department department;
   //getter setter for code, name and Department
    public String toString(){
        return this.name+" "+this.code;
    }


    public class Department{//inner class
        int departmentCode;
        String departmentName;
       //getter setter for departmentCode and departmentName
    }
}
```

OnButtonClick function i am calling updateListView which parses the json string and populate the list view. The problem here is i am unable to get Department data in list view whilst Employee data is getting populated correctly.

Here is the snip of emulator showing the list view i am getting after running code.
[image]

Can anyone correct me where i am going wrong. How can i display department data also?

Comment: Share the adapter code? are you getting any error?

Comment: @Fahim I hope you are talking about ArrayAdapter, the code is in a updateListView function. I am not getting any kind of error i am just not getting Department data in ListView only able to see Employee Data in ListView.

Comment: you need to use a custom adapter with custom layout

Comment: @Fahim Are you pretty sure that the thing i am trying to achieve is not possible without creating custom adapter and layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you're using the default ArrayAdapter, you don't really have control over much... If you want to nicely format everything and have real control over what is displayed from your custom object (which you probably do), you need to create a custom ArrayAdapter for your Employee object and override the getView() method from within there.

However, if you just want to get by this issue for now... You could just edit your Employee's override toString() method to include the Department data, like so:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String toDisplay = this.name + " " + this.code;
    if(department != null) toDisplay += "\n" + department.toString();
    return toDisplay;
}
```

And then override toString in your Department Object as well:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return departmentName;
}
```

Also, from a object-oriented standpoint, an Employee seems like it should be a member of a Department (instead of the reverse, which is what you currently have)... ie. A Department can have many Employees, but an Employee should (generally) only have one Department... At least that was my thoughts on it anyway...

Either way, good luck~

Comment: Could you kindly explain your last statement in brief.

Comment: I'll try my best! If you think about them purely as real life examples: a Company has many departments. Of those, each Department can have many employees. On the flip-side, a single Employee generally only belongs to a single department at any time. So, from a top-down Object level, I think of it more as Company > Department > Employee. Instead of how yours is currently setup, where the Department belongs to the Employee (that leaves room for lots of Department duplications). I hope that was able to better explain what I meant

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Asyntask class for parsing.
2. Use Model class with setter getter.
3. All data parse in doInbackground method of Asyntask and add in array list (create arraylist of model class).
4. Pass array list data to adapter in PostExecute method.
5. set adapter to listview.

I hope above steps will help you.

In your class you are using same object for while loop.

```
employee=new Employee();
            department=employee.new Department();
```

But it should be

```
Employee employee=new Employee();
          Department  department=employee.new Department();
```

in your while loop.

Comment: I had done same thing which you are talking about. The code i have provided is sample code. The original json string is coming through local server which i am parsing in Async way.

Comment: create separate department class and assign  its value in your object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i don't think that this solution will going to work.